# Eclipse plugins located in workspace?

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, eclipse-plugin

I run `Eclipe Oxygen2` on several Ubuntu machines. First machine has several plugins -`Sublipse` and `Darkest Dark` theme. I decided to copy first project workspace to second machine. I'm too lazy to install plugins these project might require. Can I assume that copying whole workspace also copies all plugins?

Answer (score 0):

The code for plugins are **not** in the workspace, they are in the Eclipse installation directory (or another location if the oomph installer is used).

Configuration for most plugins is in the workspace.

Comment: Ok, so if I'm lazy with plugins and settings and don't use oomph I can copy Eclipse directory with workspace in order to move to another machine?

Comment: Stop being lazy and do a proper install. Anything else may not work.

Comment: Reason I'm lazy is I wont to know how it works. And surely it is faster